# How can I update my table field create_date to current date using trigger in sql?

Tags: mysql, triggers

*Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'participant' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.*

So I want to achieve this -> once the participant is updated I want to update his create_date to current date

```
drop trigger update_user;

DELIMITER //

CREATE
    TRIGGER update_user BEFORE UPDATE
    ON Competition.participant
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        update participant
        set create_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        where id_participant = old.id_participant;
END//

DELIMITER ;

update participant 
set name = 'Rostyk'
where id_participant = 1;
```

Comment: Yuo must update NEW.create_date value, not the table.

Comment: @Akina what do you mean?

Comment: Trigger cannot affect the table which it is defined on. It can only SET the values which must be stored into current row's columns via NEW pseudotable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE
TRIGGER update_user 
BEFORE UPDATE
ON Competition.participant
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.create_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

But it is more simple to define `create_date` column as ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, and do not use triggers.

Comment: @Rostyk Oops... sorry, typo. Edited.